# JQuery plugin and react events and properties

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Trying to get a react app working with **http://getmdl.io/** just using client side code. I want a date picker and have found this http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Pretty-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Material.html which is rather nice. But I have a problem.

How do you get a jquery event hooked up to call a function on a react class.

See this code below and the comment is where I want to call it.

```
var DatePicker = React.createClass({
OnDateSelected: function (e) {
    this.props.onDateSelected(e.currentTarget.value);
},
render: function () {
    return (

        <div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
            <label className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
                <i className="material-icons">date_range</i>
            </label>
            <div className="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                <input id="datepicker" value={this.props.selectedDate} className="mdl-textfield__input" onChange={this.OnDateSelected} />
                <label className="mdl-textfield__label">Search text</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
},
componentDidUpdate: function () {
    $("#datepicker").bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ time: false, format: "DD/MM/YYYY" });


    $('#datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker().on('change', function (e, date) {
        // Call OnDateSelected here
    });

}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, put the jQuery stuff in `componentDidMount`. `componentDidUpdate` is not called on the initial render.

Secondly, in order to access `this.OnDateSelected` from the event handler context, create a reference to the original `this` object:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var that = this; // Create a reference to 'this'
    ...
    ...
    $('#datepicker').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker().on('change', function (e, date) {
        // Call OnDateSelected here
        that.OnDateSelected(e);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks that was so close to what I was trying but not quite, worked a treat.